# Pass argumets to lodash _.result

Tags: javascript, arguments, lodash

Is there a way to pass arguments to lodash `_.result`, for the case, when second attribute is method name? Or is there alternative method (preferable lodash) of doing this?

Usage example could be like this:

```
var object = {
  'cheese': 'crumpets',
  'stuff': function( arg1 ) {
    return arg1 ? 'nonsense' : 'balderdash';
  }
};

_.result(object, 'cheese');
// => 'crumpets'

_.result(object, 'stuff', true);
// => 'nonsense'

_.result(object, 'stuff');
// => 'balderdash'
```

Thank you.

Comment: The docs do not seem show any way to accomplish this https://lodash.com/docs#result (if I understand correctly) so my guess is that this is not supported. You could ask here https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues to be certain, or even request it as an additional feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the source code of lodash _.result function and there is no support for this. You can implement your own function for this and extend lodash with it using _.[mixin](https://lodash.com/docs#mixin).

```
function myResult(object, path, defaultValue) {
    result = object == null ? undefined : object[path];
    if (result === undefined) {
        result = defaultValue;
    }
    return _.isFunction(result) 
        ? result.apply(object, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 2 )) 
        : result;
}

// add our function to lodash
_.mixin({ myResult: myResult})


_.myResult(object, 'cheese');
// "crumpets"

_.myResult(object, 'stuff', true);
// "nonsense"

_.myResult(object, 'stuff');
// "balderdash"
```

Comment: Thanks for the pretty simple solution!

Comment: Just be aware that this solution does not offer the full capabilities of `_.result` in several ways.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own mixin. Here is an example using the soon to be released lodash 4.0.0

```js
var reIsDeepProp = /\.|\[(?:[^[\]]*|(["'])(?:(?!\1)[^\\]|\\.)*?\1)\]/;
var reIsPlainProp = /^\w*$/;
var rePropName = /[^.[\]]+|\[(?:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(["'])((?:(?!\2)[^\\]|\\.)*?)\2)\]/g;
var reEscapeChar = /\\(\\)?/g;

function isKey(value, object) {
  if (typeof value == 'number') {
    return true;
  }
  return !_.isArray(value) &&
    (reIsPlainProp.test(value) || !reIsDeepProp.test(value) ||
      (object != null && value in Object(object)));
}

function stringToPath(string) {
  var result = [];
  _.toString(string).replace(rePropName, function(match, number, quote, string) {
    result.push(quote ? string.replace(reEscapeChar, '$1') : (number || match));
  });
  return result;
}

function baseToPath(value) {
  return _.isArray(value) ? value : stringToPath(value);
}

function parent(object, path) {
  return path.length == 1 ? object : _.get(object, _.slice(path, 0, -1));
}

function customResult(object, path, args, defaultValue) {
  if (!isKey(path, object)) {
    path = baseToPath(path);
    var result = get(object, path);
    object = parent(object, path);
  } else {
    result = object == null ? undefined : object[path];
  }
  if (result === undefined) {
    result = defaultValue;
  }
  return _.isFunction(result) ? result.apply(object, _.isArrayLike(args) ? args : []) : result;
}

_.mixin({
  'customResult': customResult
});

var object = {
  'cheese': 'crumpets',
  'stuff': function(arg1) {
    return arg1 ? 'nonsense' : 'balderdash';
  }
};

var out = document.getElementById('out');
out.textContent = _.customResult(object, 'cheese') + '\n';
// => 'crumpets'

out.textContent += _.customResult(object, 'stuff', [true]) + '\n';
// => 'nonsense'

out.textContent += _.customResult(object, 'stuff') + '\n';
// => 'balderdash'
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/master/lodash.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

I have used the exact functions from the internal workings of lodash but you may be able to do it with just exposed methods. If I have a few minutes spare I will have a look if it is possible.

The problem with using only exposed methods is that I don't see any way to execute the function with the correct context.

> This method is like _.get except that if the resolved value is a
>   function it’s invoked with the this binding of its parent object and
>   its result is returned.

Comment: The idea is clear, thanks. So it seems like it solves more general task, like deep `result`?

Comment: In method `customResult` should be method `_.get` and later `_.slice` instead of `_slice`, I guess.

Comment: Yes, this solution works just like the original `_.result`, it just adds the `args` argument to the method.

Comment: just revealed about deep `result`, it's possible since 3d version. In 2d version `result` is not deep.

Comment: As I said, this solution is based on the soon to be released v4.0.0, so I'm sure that there many improvements compared to those previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another mixin implementation:

```
function myResult(obj, path, defaultValue) {

    // Find any arguments beyond what's normally
    // passed to result().
    var args = _.drop(arguments, 3);

    // We need to know upfront whether or not this
    // is a function we're dealing with.
    var isFunc = _.isFunction(_.get(obj, path));

    // If this is a function, and there's arguments
    // to apply, then use spread() and bindKey() to
    // return the result of calling the method with arguments.
    // Otherwise, it's just a plain call to result().
    if (isFunc && args.length) {
        return _.spread(_.bindKey(obj, path))(args);
    } else {
        return _.result(obj, path, defaultValue);
    }
}

_.mixin({ myResult: myResult });
```

The idea being that we only need to handle the added case where `path` is a function *and* additional arguments were passed. Otherwise, we revert back to the basic `result()` implementation.

```
_.myResult(object, 'test');
// → undefined

_.myResult(object, 'test', 15);
// → 15

_.myResult(object, 'cheese', 'wine');
// → "crumpets"

_.myResult(object, 'stuff');
// → "balderdash"

_.myResult(object, 'stuff', null, true);
// → "nonsense"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this now using lodash v4 [invoke](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#invoke) method, however it will throw an error if you try to call something that is not a function (undefined props are fine):

```js
var object = {
  'cheese': 'crumpets',
  'stuff': function(arg1) {
    return arg1 ? 'nonsense' : 'balderdash';
  }
};

try {
  var rst1 = _.invoke(object, 'cheese');
  // => 'Error!!'
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Error: cheese is not a function.'); 
}

var rst2 = _.invoke(object, 'stuff', true);
console.log(rst2); // => 'nonsense'

var rst3 = _.invoke(object, 'stuff');
console.log(rst3); // => 'balderdash'

var rst4 = _.invoke(object, 'bob');
console.log(rst4); // => 'undefined'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```